"Sandwich" Quadratic majorizer of even convex function
Assume $f : R \to R$ is strictly convex, differentiable, even and $f(0)=0$. Further assume that there exist quadratic functions above f.
I want to prove that for any quadratic function $ax^2 + bx + c \geq f(x)$ that is majorizing $f$, there exists another quadratic that is centered at $0$ which is "inbetween" the majorizing quadratic and $f$. That is, I want to prove that there always exists $d, e$ such that
$$
ax^2 + bx + c \geq dx^2 + e \geq f(x).
$$
The intuition is that the "tightest" quadratic upper bound on a even convex function is achieved centered at zero. Any hints on how to prove this is apprectiated!
EDIT: added strict convexity as requirement to avoid counterexample shown below
EDIT2: a counterexample was posted even for strictly convex case. I am still interested in the result for $f(x) = log(exp(x/2) + exp(-x/2)$, where I believe it to be true.

Please don't use "EDIT:".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755

A counterexample:
$$
 f(x) = \max(|x| - 2, 0) \, ,\\
 p(x) = (x-1)^2 \, .
$$
$f$ is convex, even, with $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) \le p(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.
If $q$ is an even quadratic polynomial with $f(x) \le q(x) \le p(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ then $q(1) = q(-1) = 0$ and $q(0) \ge 0$, so that $q$ is identically zero. But then $f(x) \le q(x)$ fails for $|x| > 2$.
This plot (created with wxMaxima) shows $f(x)$ (blue), $p(x)$ (red), and $p(-x)$ (green):

Here is a counterexample with strictly convex functions:
$$
 f(x) = \max(\frac 12 x^2 -3 , \frac{1}{10}(x^2-1)) \, ,\\
 p(x) = (x-1)^2 \, .
$$
Now $q$ would necessarily be of the form $q(x) = d(x^2-1)$ with $0 \le d \le 1/10$, and then $f(x) \le q(x)$ fails again for large $x$.


thanks for this counter-example.  I want to exclude situations like this, so I should add strict convexity to my requirements. do you think the statement is true in that case?

@test-account: I have added a counterexample with a stricly convex function $f$.

Thanks! I realize now the question I was asking is flawed and the result doesn't hold in the generality I thought it will. The specific convex function I was interested in is f(x) = log( exp(x/2) + exp(-x/2)), for which I believe it should hold.

@test-account: You have now modified your question twice after I answered it. I will no longer engage in this thread.
